# Fill values and shift column in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I've got a pandas dataframe looking like this:

```
    sequence  positions
0          -          8
1          N          9
2          M         10
3          S         11
4          L         12
5          V         13
6          -         14
7          E         15
8          T         16
9          V         17
10         D         18
```

In sequence column there are letters (amino acid codes) and dashes indicating gaps (in amino sequence), in column positions I want to put positions of those amino acids. They are just a sequence of numbers (in this case starting at 8), so I used `range()` to generate the column. But this numbering is about aminos, not gaps. Column positions should be filled with dashes and shifted accordingly:

```
    sequence  positions
0          -          -
1          N          8
2          M          9
3          S         10
4          L         11
5          V         12
6          -          -
7          E         13
8          T         14
9          V         15
10         D         16
```

So, i thought about iterating over rows and doing this modifictation, but pandas manual says it's a bad idea. Probably creating some function and combining it with pandas `apply` and `shift` would solve the problem, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Hi Michal, do you need to keep the dashes in the dataframe? If not, you can first drop all dashes from `sequence` and create a new  `position` column as `range(0,n)`

Comment: Yeah, it would be fast and easy, but the whole point in this case is to preserve dashes - and have 'double indexing' - via index for both codes and dashes and for codes only.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method:

```
import pandas as pd

# find out the dashes
dash = df.sequence == "-"

# assign dash to positions where sequence is dash
df.loc[dash, "positions"] = "-"

# assign a sequence of numbers to positions where sequence is not dash
df.loc[~dash, "positions"] = pd.np.arange(8, (~dash).sum()+8)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution, hope you like it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sequence': ['-', 'A', 'B', 'C', '-', 'D'], 'positions': range(8, 14)})
seq = df['sequence'].tolist()
pos = iter(df['positions'].tolist())
pos = [next(pos) if a != '-' else '-' for a in seq]
df['positions'] = pos
```

Please take note that there is no hard-coding in this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use double `.loc` accessor after forming a boolean mask by querying string values not equal to dashes `"-"`.

```
df.loc[df.sequence != "-", 'positions'] = df['positions'].values
df.loc[df.sequence == "-", 'positions'] = "-"
```

[image]